# Multiple substring searches in numpy array with few unique values

Tags: python-3.x, performance, numpy, substring

Inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60001444/can-i-find-out-if-one-numpy-vector-appears-as-a-slice-of-another#comment106114071_60001444) question: suppose that I have a list of multiple 1D `numpy` arrays `xs` and I would like to know how many occur as "substrings" of another larger 1D `numpy` array `y`.

We can assume that arrays contain integers and that `a` is a substring of `b` if `a == b[p:q]` for some integers `p` and `q`.

My proposed solution uses the `in` operator of Python's `bytes` object, but I suppose that it is inefficient if `xs` has many elements:

```
import numpy as np

N = 10_000    # number of arrays to search
M = 3         # "alphabet" size 
K = 1_000_000 # size of the target array

xs = [np.random.randint(0, M, size=7) for _ in range(N)]
y = np.random.randint(0, M, size=K)

y_bytes = y.tobytes()
%time num_matches = sum(1 for x in xs if x.tobytes() in y_bytes)
# CPU times: user 1.03 s, sys: 17 µs, total: 1.03 s
# Wall time: 1.03 s
```

If `M` is large (number of possible values in `y` of any of the `xs`'s) is large, then I imagine that little can be done to speed this up. However, for small `M` I imagine that using a trie or something of the sort could be helpful. Is there an efficient way to implement this in Python, possibly using `numpy`/`numba`?

Comment: Would all arrays in `xs` be of the same length?

Comment: See maybe here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/57004175/11610186

Comment: @Divakar sure, assuming that all arrays in `xs` have the same length is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For small `M's`, we can assign each of the `xs` a unique label based on the combination of integers in it. For the same we can leverage convolution with an *scaling* array and hence, reduce each of `xs` to a scalar. Finally, we use matching-method to detect and hence, the count.

The only over-head would be the conversion to array from the list of arrays. So, if the list-creation itself is optimized before-hand to have an array rather, it would help a lot on final performance numbers.

The implementation would look something like this -

```
x = np.asarray(xs) # convert to array, if not already done

s = M**np.arange(x.shape[1])
yr = np.convolve(y,s[::-1])
xr = x.dot(s)

# Final step : Match and get count
N = np.maximum(xr.max(),yr.max())+1 # or use s[-1]*M if M is small enough
l = np.zeros(N, dtype=bool)
l[yr] = True
count = l[xr].sum()
```

**Alternatives to perform `Final step`**

Alternative #1 :

```
sidx = yr.argsort()
idx = np.searchsorted(yr,xr,sorter=sidx)
idx[idx==len(yr)] = 0
count = (yr[sidx[idx]] == xr).sum()
```

Alternative #2 :

```
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix

ly = len(yr)
y_extent = yr.max()+1  # or use s[-1]*M if M is small enough
r = np.zeros(ly, dtype=np.uint64)
val = np.ones(ly, dtype=np.bool)
sp_mat = csr_matrix((val, (r,yr)), shape=(1,y_extent))
count = sp_mat[:,xr].sum()
```

Alternative #3 :

For bigger `M` number, we can use `empty` arrays instead -

```
l = np.empty(N, dtype=bool)
l[xr] = False
l[yr] = True
count = l[xr].sum()
```

**Digging further (Leveraging `numba` on `convolution`)**

Profiling on the main proposed solution reveals that the `1D` convolution part was the time-consuming part. Going further, we see that the `1D` convolution code has a specific kernel that is geometric  in nature. This could be implemented in `O(n)` upon re-using boundary elements per iteration. Note that this would be basically an inverted kernel as compared to the one proposed earlier. So, putting all of those changes, we end up with something like this -

```
from numba import njit

@njit
def numba1(y, conv_out, M, L, N):
    A = M**L
    for i in range(1,N):
        conv_out[i] = conv_out[i-1]*M + y[i+L-1] - y[i-1]*A
    return conv_out

def numba_convolve(y, M, L):
        N = len(y)-L+1
        conv_out = np.empty(N, dtype=int)
        conv_out[0] = y[:L].dot(M**np.arange(L-1,-1,-1))
        return numba1(y, conv_out, M, L, N)

def intersection_count(xs, y):
    x = np.asarray(xs) # convert to array, if not already done

    L = x.shape[1]
    s = M**np.arange(L-1,-1,-1)
    xr = x.dot(s)

    yr_numba = numba_convolve(y, M=M, L=L)

    # Final step : Match and get count
    N = s[0]*M
    l = np.zeros(N, dtype=bool)
    l[yr_numba] = True
    count = l[xr].sum()
    return count
```

#### Benchmarking

We will re-use the setup from the question.

```
In [42]: %%timeit
    ...: y_bytes = y.tobytes()
    ...: p = sum(1 for x in xs if x.tobytes() in y_bytes)
927 ms ± 3.57 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [43]: %timeit intersection_count(xs, y)
7.55 ms ± 71.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

As noted earlier conversion to array could be the bottleneck. So, let's time that part too -

```
In [44]: %timeit np.asarray(xs)
3.41 ms ± 10.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

So, the array-conversion part is around `45%` of total runtime and that's a substantial one. Hence, the suggestion to work with 2D array as opposed to list of 1D arrays becomes crucial at this point. The upside is array data gives us vectorized capability and hence improved performance overall. Just to emphasis on the 2D array availibility, here are the speedups with and without -

```
In [45]: 927/7.55
Out[45]: 122.78145695364239

In [46]: 927/(7.55-3.41)
Out[46]: 223.91304347826087
```